# How to show tooltip on mouseover in shape excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. I already make a maps with shape on excel. I want show information when i direct cursor to one of location. Thanks before

Answer (score 10):

We can use the property of a `Hyperlink` that can display a ToolTip on MouseOver.

I have a Shape called `MyShape`.  Running this macro:

```
Sub MeaningOfLife()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("MyShape")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), _
        Address:="", _
        ScreenTip:="The Meaning of Life Is..."

    r.Select
End Sub
```

will assign an inactive hyperlink to the Shape.

- hovering displays the ToolTip
- clicking does nothing

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One limitation of the above answer is that the shape will show the screen tip on hover but a macro assigned to the shape will not work by click.
A workaround suggested by Tim Williams:

[VBA Run Macro and Screen Tip (or Tool Tip) From Shape. I cannot get the code I found to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058747/vba-run-macro-and-screen-tip-or-tool-tip-from-shape-i-cannot-get-the-code-i-f/63059151#63059151)