# Convert Subroutines to Functions

Tags: excel, vba

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058747/vba-run-macro-and-screen-tip-or-tool-tip-from-shape-i-cannot-get-the-code-i-f), regarding using a macro and having a screentip and I received a very good idea from @Tim Williams but in order for this to work I need to convert subs into functions. I have never done that before and I don't know if it is possible but I hope one of you experts can guide me. Here are my subroutines that need to be converted for this to work.

1. Normal / Editable View - This program is run from full screen mode. So this subroutine allows the user to press a button and go to normal excel view.

   ````
   ```
   Sub ScreenDisplayNorm()
       Call UnProtectAllSheets
       With Application
           .DisplayFullScreen = False
           With ActiveWindow
               .WindowState = xlNormal
               .DisplayHeadings = True
               .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
               .DisplayGridlines = False
               .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
               .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
               .Zoom = 80
           End With
           .DisplayStatusBar = True
           .DisplayFormulaBar = True
       End With
   End Sub

   ```
   ````
2. Fullscreen View - Press button to convert view back to fullscreen!

   ````
    ```
    Sub GotoResources()

        Set wbPB = PokerBros

        Dim maxWidth As Long
        Dim myWidth As Long
        Dim Myzoom As Single
        Dim wsR As Worksheet: Set wsR = wbPB.Worksheets("Resource Data")
        Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = wsR.Range("A1:U35")

            Call UnProtectAllSheets
            wsR.Activate
            Call EnhancePerformance 'call sub to Improve speed (screen updates and calculations)
            Call ScreenDisplayMax 'call sub to maximize
            maxWidth = GetSystemMetrics(0) * 0.96 'maximum width measurement
            myWidth = ActiveSheet.Range("U1").Left 'Actual width of program starting from the left edge of the cell furthest_
        'to the right that fits the best view
            Myzoom = maxWidth / myWidth
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = Myzoom * 90
            Rng.Select
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = True 'set range zoom
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
            Call NormalPerformance 'call sub to perform normal (screen updates and calculations)
            Call ProtectAllSheets

    End Sub
    ```
   ````
3. Save - Button will save current file

   ````
    ```
    Sub SaveWorkbook()

        ActiveWorkbook.Save

    End Sub
    ```
   ````
4. SaveAs - User can save file to a different location.

   ````
    ```
    Sub SaveAsDialogBox()
            Dim CarryOn As Boolean
            Call UnProtectAllSheets
            CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to save a copy of this original file?", vbYesNo, "Save Copy Recommended")
            If CarryOn = True Then
                CopyToNewBook
            End If
    End Sub
    ```
   ````
5. Player Profile - Opens player profile userform to gather data.

   ````
    ```
    Sub OpenProfileUF()

        ufDirectory.Show vbModeless

    End Sub
    ```
   ````
6. Import Data - Allows user to calculate results

   ````
    ```
    Sub UpdateArray()

        Dim wsDest As Worksheet
        Dim arSource() As Variant, arDest() As Variant, varID As Variant, ImportDate As Variant
        Dim outputColumns As Variant, inputColumns As Variant
        Dim filename As String: filename = "C:\Users\AdamRhodes\OneDrive\Desktop\PokerBros\PokerBrosSuppliment.xlsm"
        Dim strDest As String, lastsrcrow As Long, AddRow As Integer, strfilename As String
        Dim lrow As Long, CarryOn As Boolean, MsgAnswer As Integer

        Set wbPB = PokerBros
        Set wsPT = wbPB.Worksheets("Player Tracking")

            Call UnProtectAllSheets
            Call EnhancePerformance
            CarryOn = MsgBox("Running this macro will import" & "," & "extract" & "," & _
        "and compute data from other files and will add calculations to some reporting" & "." & "It is recommended to save a copy to restore with confidence" & "." & "If you already saved a copy and wish to proceed select ""Yes"" and select ""No"" to exit and save a copy" & "!", vbYesNo, "Please Approve Data Load")

            If CarryOn = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            MsgAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to select your filepath? If you select ""NO"" The application will attempt to open the file" & ".", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Locate File to Export Data!")

            If MsgAnswer = vbYes Then
                strfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse and Select you Newest PokerBrosSuppliment.xls file", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
                Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename:=strfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
            ElseIf MsgAnswer = vbNo Then
                On Error Resume Next 'Call function to check if the file is open
                If IsFileOpen(filename) = False Then 'Insert actions to be performed on the closed file
                    Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename, ReadOnly:=True)
                Else: MsgBox filename & " is already open." 'The file is open or another error occurred
                    Set wbSource = Workbooks("PokerBrosSuppliment.xlsm") 'open the file manually
                    If IsError(Error) Then 'if there is an error opening the file it may already be open.
                        strfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse and Select you Newest PokerBrosSuppliment.xls file", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
                        Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename:=strfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
                    Else: Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename:=strfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf MsgAnswer = vbCancel Then
                MsgBox "No file has been selected" & "." & "File has not been imported" & "!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Procedure was Cancelled"
            Exit Sub
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Export")
                'use last row from suppliment to determine how many formatted rows needed for player tracking
            lastsrcrow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            AddRow = lastsrcrow - rCntr 'rcntr is a constant 150. so the last row minus 150 determines how many formatted rows to be added.
            wsPT.Activate ' activate Player Tracking
            Call AddNew_Worksheet 'call sub to add new worksheet
            strDest = wbPB.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name 'rename the new spreadsheet

            Set wsDest = wbPB.Worksheets(strDest) 'set the worksheet object
            If AddRow > 0 Then 'Add rows if needed
                wsDest.Rows(rCntr + 1 & ":" & AddRow + rCntr + 1).Select 'determine how many rows to add
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'select the range and insert rows
                With wsDest
                    .Range("B150:N150").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B150:N" & AddRow + 151), Type:=xlFillDefault 'autofill from cells above to format
                End With
            End If

            inputColumns = Array(6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 23, 35, 36) 'source array data
            outputColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13) 'Destination array data
            Call writeArray(inputColumns, outputColumns) 'write the array
            Call Get_RakeBack_Rates 'call sub to insert Rake Back Rates
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'hide alert about closing the source file with data on the clipboard
            wbSource.Close savechanges:=False 'close workbook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'activate alerts again
            Call NormalPerformance
            Call ProtectAllSheets

     End Sub
    ```
   ````
7. Directory Adds - Adds new accounts to the directory.

   ````
    ```
    Sub DirectoryAdds()

    Set wbPB = PokerBros

    Dim srcColumns As Variant: srcColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14)
    Dim tgtColumns As Variant: tgtColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12)
    Dim wsIT As Worksheet: Set wsIT = wbPB.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Dim wsPD As Worksheet: Set wsPD = wbPB.Worksheets("Player Directory")
    Dim Rng As Range, rngSource As Range, c As Range
    Dim Curr, ub As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Dim wsPDlastrow As Long: wsPDlastrow = wsPD.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastrow As Long, inc As Integer, FillRow As Integer, NextRow As Integer, lastRR As Long

        Call UnProtectAllSheets
        Call EnhancePerformance
        ub = UBound(srcColumns) 'Player Tracking UBound column count
        If wsIT Is wsPD Then    'If Player Directory sheet is Activesheet exit sub. Player Tracking needs to be active at start of macro
            MsgBox "Wrong sheet selected."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'set source range from Player Tracking
        Set rngSource = wsIT.Range(wsIT.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcColumns(0)), wsIT.Cells(Rows.Count, srcColumns(0)).End(xlUp))

        For Each c In rngSource.Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                'Simpler to search full column, but assumes there will be no match in the header or the cells above it.
                Curr = Application.Match(c.Value, wsPD.Columns(tgtColumns(0)), 0) 'no Worksheetfunction=no runtime error if no match
                If Not IsError(Curr) Then 'increment last column
                    For inc = 5 To 10
                        If inc > 10 Then Exit For
                        If inc = 6 Or inc = 7 Then
                            GoTo SKIP_ITERATION:
                        End If
                        With wsPD.Cells(Curr, tgtColumns(inc))
                            .Value = .Value + wsIT.Cells(c.Row, srcColumns(inc)).Value
                        End With
        SKIP_ITERATION:     Next inc
                Else
                    Set Rng = wsPD.Cells(Rows.Count, tgtColumns(0)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'no 
        match: copy over
                    For k = 0 To ub
                        wsPD.Cells(Rng.Row, tgtColumns(k)).Value = wsIT.Cells(c.Row, srcColumns(k)).Value
                    Next k
                End If
            End If
            lastrow = wsPD.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            With wsPD.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2)
                .EntireRow.Copy
                .EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next c

        For Each c In wsPD.Range("B4:M" & lastrow)    'locate all blank rows in player details cells
            If IsEmpty(c) Then
                c.Value = "None" 'Put "TBD" in all blank cells
            End If
        Next c

        MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."
        Call NormalPerformance
        Call ProtectAllSheets

    End Sub
    ```
   ````

Comment: Changing a `Sub` to a `Function` is as simple as replace `Sub` to `Function` (i.e. `Sub SomeTest()` to `Function SomeTest()`). However, there are a few things you need to consider (i.e. what is it that you want to return? what is it the requesting UDF requires? Data type that each function should return? ... etc)

Comment: My whole problem is based around having a screen tip and macro assigned to a shape. I need the macro be as a function to make the code that I would like to use work. That question is in another post ["Click Here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058747/vba-run-macro-and-screen-tip-or-tool-tip-from-shape-i-cannot-get-the-code-i-f)

Comment: `Functions`, with rare exceptions, cannot alter the environment. They can only return a value. So it is unlikely you will be able to convert all of your `Subs` to `Functions` and have them run successfully.

Comment: You should post an exact description on what you're trying to achieve and not forcing people to go through two walls of text and code just to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kostas K. - I thought my question was pretty straight forward... "I would like to know if my subs can be converted to functions". The link was supplimental information and I wasnt forcing anyone to do anything. Sorry you didn't understand my question.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld thank you. I was thinking that I would have a problem getting the same results out of the sub versus the function. But I thank you for your thoughts. Looks like Im back to the drawing board.

Comment: The post that you referenced stated the code does not work.  It will never work.  You will need to hook the Mouse Down event.

Comment: Thank you @TinMan. I will try something else then.

Comment: *Here are my subroutines that need to be converted for this to work.* You are not looking only to convert subs to functions but you need *this to work*. What exactly is *this*?

Comment: @Kostas K. I have some other code that can run a macro and a screentip on a shape, but the macro needs to be a function. The other code is supplimental and I included a link but it doesn't appear these subs can be converted to functions anyway. At least that appears to be the general concensus.

Comment: I would make a factory method to create and group two shapes.  One shape for the macro and the second for the ScreenTip.  Here is a demo:  [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e8GoIacZ_WoBRVhMJ3qHLSBSmmw3s2gB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The question is too broad actually since there might be several issues with this process, and the _op_ has not followed [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) principles in the post. It seems unlikely the _op_ is completely unfamiliar with _how_ to write `Function` statements, but rather they should be asking about specific problems in converting one of the subroutines into functions.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a Sub to a Function, you simply need to change the definition from `Sub xxx` to `Function xxx`, the closing `End Sub` to `End Function` and any `Exit Sub` to `Exit Function`. That`s all - however it will be rather useless to do so.

None of these functions will return anything, and the basic idea of a function is to return something (in opposite to a sub that cannot return anything - in other programming languages this is called a void function). The question is *why* you want to convert it to a function and *what* you want to return?

To let a function return anything, you simply assign a value to the function name. So if you have a function `foo`, you write:

```
Function foo
    (...)
    foo = "Hello world"
end Function
```

Now, the function will return the string "Hello world". You should declare the type that is returned by the function (else it will return a variant):

```
Function doubleMe(x as Long) As Long
    (...)
    doubleMe = x * 2
End Function
```

and use the result on your code

```
myVal = doubleMe(12345)
y1 = 555
Debug.Print doubleMe(y1) & " is twice as much as " & y1
```

If you are not interested in the result you can call the function like any subroutine, either with `Call` (and use parenthesis for the parameter) or without (then you have to omit the parenthesis)

```
doubleMe 0
Call doubleMe(-1)
```

Often you see that a function returns a Boolean indicating the success

```
Function ToSomethingComplicated(p1, p2, p3) as boolean
    ToSomethingComplicated = False  
    (do your complicated stuff here)
    if (something failed) Then Exit Function
    (do some more complicated stuff)
    (...)
    ' If everything was successfull, return True
    ToSomethingComplicated = True
End Function
```

Comment: The basis for needing to convert them is to be used in this code ["Click Here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058747/vba-run-macro-and-screen-tip-or-tool-tip-from-shape-i-cannot-get-the-code-i-f). Is it possible for the subs I listed above to carry out their current behavior while being functions instead of subs?

Comment: Just try: Change `Sub` to `Function` (VBA Editor will automatically change the matching `End Sub`). Return whatever you want/need to return, if I understand correctly you want to call a function via Hyperlink, so put a statement like `Set ScreenDisplayNorm=ActiveCell` at the end of the function. In opposite of what's stated in the discussions, a function can do everything a sub does - except if it is used as `UDF`.